# How to switch to bash shell from some other shell?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am running a shell script "envsetup.sh" and I keep getting the following error.

```
Badly placed ()'s
```

I found out the error is because I am not in a bash shell environment.  Can anyone help explain how to enter the `bash` shell environment?

Comment: It'd be extremely helpful if you can post the part of your script that is causing this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  How do you expect us to help you if you don't show us the code that is causing the trouble.  Please try debugging with `bash -x envsetup.sh`.  Which shell are you using if it isn't `bash`?  If you write `echo $SHELL`, it should probably tell you.  If you're using `csh`, then you might use `exec bash`, and then type `source envsetup.sh`, and then (maybe) `exec csh` to switch back to `csh`.  You may be able to use the `chsh` program to switch your login shell permanently.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I just need to know who to change the shell to bash..

Comment: @user2341103 You can't change the shell in the middle of a script without losing all your state. Before we can tell you how to change your shell, we need to know how you got _into_ that shell to start with. Is it the one associated with your OS account? Is it the shell in the shebang (the first line) of a script which, in turn, sourced your `envsetup.sh`? Etc. The additional information is _absolutely necessary_ to be certain that we can provide a correct answer; otherwise, folks are guessing at the details.

Comment: Try running `bash -vx envsetup.sh` it will show you each executed subcommand up to the error... Maybe your script is using some bashism and your shell is something else (`dash` perhaps?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to compile Android, you can do the following to temporarily use bash:

```
$ bash
$ source ./envsetup.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

To switch to a `bash` login shell (which reads profiles etc), you should type:

```
exec bash -l
```

The `-l` option indicates that it should be a login shell.  You can then read the `envsetup.sh` file using:

```
source envsetup.sh
```

You may be able to use the `chsh` command to change your login shell permanently using a line such as:

```
chsh /bin/bash
```

Just make sure the name you specify is the correct path to your copy of `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of your script.
I am assuming the bash command file is in /bin - if not have a look for where it is located and use that path instead.

Comment: If the problem is setting up environment (as the name `envsetup.sh` suggests), this probably won't help.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter whether bash is in /bin.   The #!/bin/bash is a convention:  it doesn't map it to an actual executable file.

Comment: @Curt: It does matter in general, and it does map to an executable file.  Try using `#!/no/where/bash` and then try running the script as `envsetup.sh` (or `./envsetup.sh`), and watch for the 'command not found' error.  If you source it (`source envsetup.sh` or `. envsetup.sh`), it won't matter, but there are specific reasons for that.

Comment: Can I go back to your original query and ask if you really want to change to the bash shell? Is the problem not that the syntax of some code in your script is bash specific? Would it be more useful to look at using syntax that works in sh, csh, ksh or whatever shell you are actually in? p.s. You could also use >/bin/bash ./envsetup.sh

Comment: Another consideration is the use of >. ./envsetup.sh to apply the changes in your script to your current shell.

Comment: @Curt The shebang line is how the operating system finds the executable interpreter to use to run a script. As such, no, it is not merely convention.

Answer (score 0):

to run a single script `envsetup.sh` in `bash`, invoke it like this:

```
bash envsetup.sh
```